# How to declare nullable field in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

The `stock_symbol` is optional, it exists only for some companies, what would be proper way to declare it in Nim?

Do I have to use `ref` or there's other way?

```
type
  Company = object
    name:         string
    stock_symbol: string

echo Company(name: "Microsoft", stock_symbol: "MSFT")
echo Company(name: "Kinetic",   stock_symbol: nil)
```

And similar question for composite type, usually you need to know both stock exchange and the symbol

```
type
  SymbolWithExchange = object
    exchange: string
    symbol:   string

  Company2 = object
    name:         string
    stock_symbol: SymbolWithExchange

echo Company2(
  name:         "Microsoft", 
  stock_symbol: SymbolWithExchange("NYSE", "MSFT")
)
echo Company2(name: "Kinetic",   stock_symbol: nil)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like `Option[T]` should be used

```
import options

type
  Company = object
    name:         string
    stock_symbol: Option[string]

echo Company(name: "Microsoft", stock_symbol: some("MSFT"))
echo Company(name: "Kinetic",   stock_symbol: none(string))
```

and

```
import options

type
  SymbolWithExchange = object
    exchange: string
    symbol:   string

  Company2 = object
    name:         string
    stock_symbol: Option[SymbolWithExchange]

echo Company2(
  name:         "Microsoft", 
  stock_symbol: some(SymbolWithExchange(exchange: "NYSE", symbol: "MSFT"))
)
echo Company2(name: "Kinetic",   stock_symbol: none(SymbolWithExchange))
```